# Stop Devise from clearing session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

It seems when a user logs out via standard Devise controllers, Devise destroys the entire session store, not just its own data. Is there any way to avoid this behavior? I have other irrelevant data that should be kept around.

```
session[:my_var] = "123"
```

Log out via devise...

```
puts session[:my_var]
# => nil
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `destroy`¹ method of `SessionsController` contains the following line:

```
signed_out = Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
```

The `sign_out_all_scopes`² method calls `warden.logout` without any arguments, and the `sign_out`³ method calls `warden.logout(scope)`.

The documentation of the `logout`⁴ method states:

> ```
> # Logout everyone and clear the session
> env['warden'].logout
>
> # Logout the default user but leave the rest of the session alone
> env['warden'].logout(:default)
> ```

Conclusion: `sign_out` should preserve the session when given a specific scope. However, I don't see any way to do that. `sign_out_all_scopes` is *always* called first, and will only return `false` if it couldn't log any user out.

I recommend either [posting a feature request](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/new) on their issue tracker or developing your own authentication solution. Rails now provides [`has_secure_password`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password), and these days people seem to be going for the latter in order to avoid running into these problems.

---

¹ [`Devise::SessionsController#destroy`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L20)

² [`Devise::Controllers::Helpers#sign_out_all_scopes`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L149)

³ [`Devise::Controllers::Helpers#sign_out`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L137)

⁴ [`Warden::Proxy#logout`](https://github.com/hassox/warden/blob/master/lib/warden/proxy.rb#L218)

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts, Matheus.

Comment: This appears to have changed in the code and your links don't have the commit hash in them. Today, `Devise.sign_out_all_scopes` is a boolean: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/ee01bac8b0b828b3da0d79c46115ba65c433d6c8/lib/devise.rb#L220

Answer (score 46):

In the lasts versions of devise it is not necesary to override the sessions controller, instead you can just use:

```
config.sign_out_all_scopes = false
```

In the `devise.rb` file to get the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 16):

You could just override Devise's SessionController, like I did to preserve a shopping cart:

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

    def destroy
        order_id = session[:order_id] 
        super  
        session[:order_id] = order_id
    end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }
```

Comment: Great simple solution! Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Simple solution, you don't mess with Devise working so the risk of unexpected behaviour is very low.

Comment: i wish this worked for when devise uses timeoutable. this method is never hit then :(

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Mattheus. The statement

```
signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
```

is perhaps the best general log out statement, considering the possibility of being signed in with multiple roles. If, for you case, your user is just signed in as one role, and you want to preserve the rest of the session on signout, the easiest way is to do:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git
$ cd devise
$ git branch my_devise
$ git checkout my_devise
```

Open app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb in your editor. In the method destroy, replace

```
signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
```

with

```
signed_out = sign_out(resource_name)
```

Save and exit editor and do

```
$ git commit -am "remove only warden data from session on logout, preserve other data."
```

In the Gemfile of your project, describe the dependency to devise like

```
gem 'devise', :path => "[YOUR PATH]/devise", :branch => "my_devise"
```