# Devise - after_sign_out_path_for - depending on user attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In an earlier version of Devise (3.2) it was possible to access the user that had just signed out in the `after_sign_out_path_for(resource)` method and redirect according to any given attribute of that user.

In Devise 3.4 the method `after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)` just receives the class name as a symbol for the parameter `resource_or_scope`, i.e. `:user` in my case.

Is there another way of redirecting a given user after signing out based on the value of an attribute in the user model?

To clarify: I do not intend to create different user classes just for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same need, and I took a different approach (since the act of logging out clears out your session) -- use an instance variable instead of session to store the user

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def destroy
    @user = current_user
    super
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    if @user.some_method?
       path_a
    else
       path_b
    end
  end
end
```

And, of course, in `config/routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: "sessions"}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the exactly the same problem a while ago, and i couldn't found a way of doing it in a clean way. So to resolve that i just made a simple override to devise SessionsController in which i would save the desired attribute in session before Devise erased it:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def sign_out
    company_slug = session[:company_slug]
    super
    session[:company_slug] = company_slug
  end
end
```

And then on my after_sign_out_path_for i could do something like this:

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if session[:company_slug] == 'something'
    something_path
  end
end
```

Of Course you don`t really need to override signout method, you could simply use

> [config.sign_out_all_scopes = false in devise.rb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153040/stop-devise-from-clearing-session)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Your answer does need a bit of tweaking before it actually works.

The method to override actually is `destroy` (not `sign_out`). And when I called it with `super` it still didn't work, since the original session controller redirects to `after_sign_out_path_for` before `session[:nosponsor]` is set. So I had to override the whole method.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def destroy
    nosponsor = current_user && current_user.sponsor.blank?
    signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out if signed_out && is_flashing_format?
    yield if block_given?
    session[:nosponsor] = "true" if nosponsor
    respond_to do |format|
      format.all { head :no_content }
      format.any(*navigational_formats) { redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
    end
  end
end
```

Additionally for this to work, there needs to be an entry in `routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users, :controllers =>  {:sessions =>  "sessions"}
```

I'd like to give you credit for your answer. So if you update it to incorporate these changes, I will accept it as the correct one. Thx again.

Comment: I had just to overwrite the `after_sign_out_path_for` method. I didn't have to overwrite the `destroy` method and it worked. I'm using Devise 4.7.3.