# Redirect works for Login but not Logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, authentication, devise, logout

## Explanation

I am using the devise gem with a Ruby on Rails webapp and following this tutorial on how to redirect the user back to their previous page after they login and logout. The problem is, that the code seems to work for the login part, but logout always redirects the user to the root_path.

## Question

As I followed the tutorial exactly, and the redirect works for one, have I missed a typo or is there code elsewhere that is overwriting this code?

## Versions Used

Ruby: ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

Rails: Rails 4.2.0

Devise: 3.4.1

## Code

The Application Controller:

```
## app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  after_filter :store_location
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def store_location
    # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.
    return unless request.get? 
    if (request.path != "/login" &&
        request.path != "/logout" &&
        request.path != "/register" &&
        request.path != "/users/password/" &&
        request.path != "/users/password/new" &&
        request.path != "/users/password/edit" &&
        request.path != "/users/confirmation" &&
        request.path != "/profile/" &&
        request.path != "/profile/edit" &&
        request.path != "/admin/dashboard" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_users" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_events" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_event_items" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_companies" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_locations" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_stories" &&
        !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
      session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
    end
  end

  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   session[:previous_url] || root_path
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    session[:previous_url] || root_path
  end

end
```

The Routes file:

```
## app/config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  ## Site's Root Route
  root 'pages#home'

  ## Static Page Routes
  get 'home' => 'pages#home'
  get 'about' => 'pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'pages#contact'
  get 'privacy' => 'pages#privacy'
  get 'sitemap' => 'pages#sitemap'

  ## Administrative Routes
  get 'admin/dashboard'
  get 'admin/moderate_users'
  get 'admin/moderate_events'
  get 'admin/moderate_event_items'
  get 'admin/moderate_companies'
  get 'admin/moderate_locations'
  get 'admin/moderate_stories'

  ## Customed Devise Routes
  devise_for  :users, 
              :skip => [:sessions, :registrations]

  devise_scope :user do
    get    "login",               to: "devise/sessions#new",            as: :new_user_session
    post   "login",               to: "devise/sessions#create",         as: :user_session
    delete "logout",              to: "devise/sessions#destroy",        as: :destroy_user_session

    get    "register",            to: "devise/registrations#new",       as: :new_user_registration
    post   "register",            to: "devise/registrations#create",    as: :user_registration
    get    "account/delete",      to: "devise/registrations#cancel",    as: :cancel_user_registration

    get    "user/profile/edit",   to: "devise/registrations#edit",      as: :edit_user_registration

    patch  "user",                to: "devise/registrations#update"
    put    "user",                to: "devise/registrations#update"
    put    "register",            to: "devise/registrations#update"
    delete "user/delete",         to: "devise/registrations#destrony"

    get    "user/profile",        to: 'devise/registrations#edit',      as: :user_root
  end

end
```

Nothing of consequence in the ApplicationHelper file.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It might be due to the `after_sign_out_path_for(resource)`

Comment: I agree. It looks like it it would be with that piece of code. But, it is copied exactly from the tutorial and is valid for the Devise gem as well. Is it possible that this code at the top of the ApplicationController is not being called during a logout?  `after_filter :store_location`  I am not sure when the `after_filter` is normally run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your session variable is being set to nil on logout, hence the redirect to the root path.

Try the below setting to the keep session scope irrelevant to logout.

> ```
> config.sign_out_all_scopes = false
> ```
>
> in the devise.rb file to get the desired behaviour

ref: [Stop Devise from clearing session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153040/stop-devise-from-clearing-session)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I set this variable in the devise.rb file, and restarted the server and it definitely works now. Thank you! My app now returns the user to their previous page on both login and logout. (Unless the page is protected.)

Comment: A unique anomaly is that, if the user is on a restricted page when they logout, they are not redirected to the root_path, as I would expect them to, but they are redirected to the previous page they were on when they first logged in. But, when logging out from an unsecured page, they are redirected back to that page, even if it wasn't the one they were on before they logged in. ... This may need to be posted as another question. I will work on it for a while to try and figure it out first. Thank you again @Rots for your solution!

Comment: @ChristopherWarrington Yes there are issues with choosing correct pages when it comes to routing and secure/insecure pages. I'm sure you'll figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can customize `after_sign_out_path_for(resource)` if you want to redirect the user back to their previous page after they logout like below

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
   request.referrer
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Pavan, but that won't work for me when the referred page is locked down. When the user signs out they won't be able to access that referred page and would be kicked to the login page with an error. I don't want a user who just signed out to be kicked to a login page and told that they can't access a page unless they are signed in. I would like to keep the code as I have it, I just don't know why my `def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)` section is not working when the `def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` is. Thank you though, for the suggestion.