# Simplifying code in Rails ApplicationController for URL Paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simplify

## Question

I have the following code (see below) and was wondering if there is anyway to simplify the code so that any page that starts with a `/admin/` or `/users/` prefix will be recognized and I wouldn't need to list them all.

## Explanation

Mainly because as the site grows and more admin and user pages are added, this list could become dozens of links long, if not more. So, is there a way to let ruby know to skip anything with the prefix `/admin/` or `/users/` like so?

```
request.path != "/users/..." &&
request.path != "/admin/..." &&
```

## Versions Used

Ruby: ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

Rails: Rails 4.2.0

Devise: 3.4.1

## Code

Specific Code:

```
## app/controllers/application_controller.rb

  def store_location
    return unless request.get? 
    if (request.path != "/login" &&
        request.path != "/logout" &&
        request.path != "/register" &&
        request.path != "/users/password/" &&
        request.path != "/users/password/new" &&
        request.path != "/users/password/edit" &&
        request.path != "/users/confirmation" &&
        request.path != "/profile/" &&
        request.path != "/profile/edit" &&
        request.path != "/admin/dashboard" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_users" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_events" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_event_items" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_companies" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_locations" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_stories" &&
        !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
      session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
    end
  end
```

Full Application Controller:

```
## app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  after_filter :store_location
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def store_location
    # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.
    return unless request.get? 
    if (request.path != "/login" &&
        request.path != "/logout" &&
        request.path != "/register" &&
        request.path != "/users/password/" &&
        request.path != "/users/password/new" &&
        request.path != "/users/password/edit" &&
        request.path != "/users/confirmation" &&
        request.path != "/profile/" &&
        request.path != "/profile/edit" &&
        request.path != "/admin/dashboard" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_users" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_events" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_event_items" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_companies" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_locations" &&
        request.path != "/admin/moderate_stories" &&
        !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
      session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
    end
  end

  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   session[:previous_url] || root_path
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    session[:previous_url] || root_path
  end

end
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!request.path.start_with?("/admin", "/users")
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F

Comment: No problem @ChristopherWarrington, don't forget to mark the question as 'answered' if it suits your purpose.

Comment: I was waiting to test the code to make sure that it is working in my app before I marked it as answered. The problem is, I can't test your code right now due to another question I have going.  As of right now, my code runs on Login, and users can't be on an `/admin` or a `/user` page before logging in. But, they can before logging out. And since my code isn't running when a person logs out, I can't test it. :-) Make sense. Once, I figure out that the problem and can test your code, and see that it is correct, I will of course mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Oh, here is the link to the other question: [Redirect works for Login but not Logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361265/redirect-works-for-login-but-not-logout). Thank you so much @Rots for your answer though. I really do appreciate your guidance.

Comment: @ChristopherWarrington I understand that you cannot test this until your other problem is resolved. I have placed an answer on your other question.

Comment: and your answer on the other question was spot on as well. Thank you. With that fixed, it looks like your code here is working and can be verified. So, I have marked this question answered. I did post a comment on the other question about an anomaly that I found in this redirecting code. I am going to work on it before I post it as another question. The only way to learn is to first try to figure it out yourself, right?

Comment: @ChristopherWarrington Yes indeed, trying yourself is encouraged.