# devise destroy all session but i need save one key after logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When you exit, the device destroys the entire session at once. But I need one session key not to be affected (in other words, after logging out to have 1 key in the session). How to do it? Of course, I understand that somehow you can save the value in a session somewhere else, and after the release again, write it down. But maybe there is a more elegant solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153040/stop-devise-from-clearing-session    See the answer with maximum votes, not the one that is marked as accepted. If you need to clear the whole session but one value, see the `@manafire`'s answer.

Comment: thanx, solved problem!